# What is the meaning of Q1, Q2, and cR values when using the get_statistics method in Pykrige?

Tags: python

I am trying to use ordinary kriging method in Pykrige to interpolate the air temperature. The get_statistics method provides three criteria for the variogram fit, which are Q1, Q2, and cR. I may miss something about the explanation of these three values. Are these criteria similar to the mean error, root mean square error or root mean square standardized error?

I am also confused that the best R²_score is negative when using the demo codes of Krige CV to get the best parameters. Is it possibly caused by a few data points?

Thank you very much in advance!

It is really helpful to me if these three criteria could be used to determine the best parameters setting in Pykrige.